# aws-cdk aws-cli cloudformation generating extra characters in arn

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-cdk

I am using the aws-cdk to create cloudformation templates, really just SNS and SQS. My problem is that the names of the generated Topics and Queues are not what I see in the yaml file.

Here is the TypeScript for the CDK:

```ts
export class TheQThingStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'ExampleQueue');
    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'ExampleTopic');
    topic.addSubscription(new subs.SqsSubscription(queue));
  }
}
```

Generated yaml:

```yml
Resources:
  ExampleQueue4CEF454C:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: dev/ExampleQueue/Resource
  ExampleQueuePolicy3CE69BA4:
    Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sqs:SendMessage
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn:
                  Ref: ExampleTopic65117661
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: sns.amazonaws.com
            Resource:
              Fn::GetAtt:
                - ExampleQueue4CEF454C
                - Arn
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      Queues:
        - Ref: ExampleQueue4CEF454C
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: dev/ExampleQueue/Policy/Resource
  ExampleQueuedevExampleTopic2BB620969F483AE8:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
    Properties:
      Protocol: sqs
      TopicArn:
        Ref: ExampleTopic65117661
      Endpoint:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - ExampleQueue4CEF454C
          - Arn
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: dev/ExampleQueue/devExampleTopic2BB62096/Resource
  ExampleTopic65117661:
    Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: dev/ExampleTopic/Resource
  CDKMetadata:
    Type: AWS::CDK::Metadata
    Properties:
      Modules: aws-cdk=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-iam=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-kms=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-sns=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-sns-subscriptions=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/aws-sqs=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/core=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/cx-api=1.22.0,@aws-cdk/region-info=1.22.0,jsii-runtime=node.js/v12.11.1
```

If I run `cdk deploy` or `aws cloudformation create-stack dev --template-body file://the-template.yaml`, those names get mangled.

```sh
$ aws sqs list-queues                                                                                            {
    "QueueUrls": [
        "https://region.queue.amazonaws.com/SECRET/dev-ExampleQueue4CEF454C-J3YMCE8ER8LW"
    ]
}
```

```sh
$ aws sns list-topics                                                                                         
{
    "Topics": [
        {
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:region:SECRET:dev-ExampleTopic65117661-1HEC7UGNZNT9U"
        }
    ]
}
```

I understand that the numbers that come after the name are a hash of the path. `dev-ExampleTopic65117661` -> `65117661` is the hash.

Where does the `1HEC7UGNZNT9U` come from?! Is cloudformation generating it? I can't find it anywhere in the code? Is that number created by AWS once submitted? Why?

If I do:

```sh
$ aws sqs create-queue --queue-name my-queue
{
    "QueueUrls": [
        "https://region.queue.amazonaws.com/SECRET/my_queue"
    ]
}
```

I don't get the extra numbers at the end of the name. What gives? It must be some part of cloudformation.

**ANSWER:**

I accepted the answer below, here is a code sample:

```ts
export class TheQThingStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, 'ExampleQueue', { queueName: `${id}-ExampleQueue` });
    const topic = new sns.Topic(this, 'ExampleTopic', { topicName: `${id}-ExampleTopic` });
    topic.addSubscription(new subs.SqsSubscription(queue));
  }
}
```

I thought `ExampleQueue` and `ExampleTopic` were names. They are `ID`s. If you pass a `name`, it overrides everything else. If you do not pass a `name`, it constructs a `logicalId` out of your `ID`, the `stackId` and a hash. So use names!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify a name for something CloudFormation will generate a name based on the name of the stack and the name of the resource. They will add some extra to the end of it to make sure it's unique.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-name.html

Comment: Why does it not need the name when I specify the queue one at a time?

Comment: Totally works though! Just wasted 3 days on this because it isn't anywhere in the CDK documentation. Heads up though, you have to pass the stack-id into the name, unless you want your names to collide.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but when you reference the queue within the stack it is using the the Fn::Ref (!Ref) or Fn::GetAtt (!GetAtt) functions to resolve the full name/ARN.

Comment: I am realizing that when I do `aws sqs create-queue --queue-name whatever` it creates the queue with name, its right there in the text. But when I use the CDK, what I thought was a 'name' is really the 'id' and the name gets generated. I find that confusing. :)